# Xcode Image Slicing Not Working with Gradients?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I have PNG images with rounded corners, inner shadows and a fill gradient, that I thought I could slice in Asset Catalogs horizontal and vertically. But no matter what I try, the gradient slice doesn't stretch or tile as I expected. With Xcode 9.1.

The gradient is not copied (although the inner shadow is), and in IB and the simulator, there are just two bars and no gradient.

What am I missing?

Here are the original image:

[image: Thumbnails of image]

Here's how I sliced them:

[image: Slicing attributes]

And what they looked like in IB:

[image: IB automatic slicing]

And here's what it looks like in IB (with the colors reversed in the simulator (with a red view and another similar image as background without any gradient) and device.

[image: no gradient just bars]

Answer (score 0):

The center is the part that is getting tiled. You defined a 1x1 square that’s getting repeated on the interior of your image in order to make the image fill the space you defined, which isn’t your stated goal. What you can do is change your center to Stretches, and increase the center’s height and width to take up everything in your image that doesn’t include your rounded corners end caps.